# PayPal API for personal accounts

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have looked into the PayPal API but it seems to require a business account & app initialized.

I am looking to have very less payments, so I am sticking to a personal account for now. Is it possible for me to still somehow use API payments under a personal account.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for your own use, upgrade to a business account. It's as free as a personal account.

Comment: Its just for minor and personal usage. I don't want to upgrade to a business account yet. Would it still be possible using the Classic NVP/SOAP integration? Accepting payments on a personal and having the proper IPN callbacks to mark them as paid.

Comment: No-------------